Can I be in a leave of absence as a postdoc in Germany?
I am employed by a German university in an ERC grant. I was wondering if I can ask for a leave of absence from the position, while being able to come back.

Have you checked with the university yet? Folks there might have somewhat better insight into its policies.

I assume this would depend on the reasons. You might elaborate here (or not).

Can you clarify what exactly you intend to do? I find several meanings for "leave of absence" and Germany being Germany we do have rules for just about anything. Taking leave for family, research or work would all use different mechanisms, for example.

@MisterMiyagi taking time away to teach at a different university and then come back on my job, so in practice like a "teaching intership" of around 4 months

@user1868607 If it's not for a full-time teaching position (say, teaching one lecture only) that might actually be possible without leave. For example, one of my colleagues holds a lecture at another university about 1hr drive away from our main campus while still having her original position at our university.

@MisterMiyagi problem is these are places in two different countries (reachable by plane)

This will highly depend on the concrete circumstances for which you will have to talk to your superior and the people at your university - however there are some regulations that are likely to apply.
If you are employed under TV-L/TVöD, the following paragraphs may be relevant (highly paraphrased, not legal advice!):
§28 Sonderurlaub leave without pay may be granted under special circumstances
§29 Arbeitsbefreiung leave with pay may be granted for partner giving birth/death in family/illness in family/doctor visit, with a specified number of days for the different cases (mostly ranging from one to four days)

Leave without pay is mostly down to an agreement between employee and employer. One example I have seen was a postdoc leaving for three months for a private trip through India. The institute was fine with it so it was granted.

Yeah I guess my point was that in general it is possible to get approved for leave without pay - could've been said better
